# Setting the argument/parameter in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments

I've been working on an assignment for class, beginners C#. I've hit a point where I do not know what to do next. This is the question and it involves argument/parameters...

Define the output of the "area" property calculation such that a user can initialize an instance of the "Circle" class by setting the argument/parameternamed"radius" (in the Constructor) and subsequently call a method named "ShowArea" to display the area of the new circle instance using the formula: (where r = radius, A = area, π= pi)

This is what I have so far:

```
 namespace IndividualAssignment2
 {
     public class Shape
     {
         public virtual int area { get; set; }
     }

     public class Circle : Shape
     {
         double radius;
         public override int area { get; set; }
         double ShowArea = 3.14 * Math.Pow(radius,2);
     }

     public sealed class Square : Shape
     {
         int height;
     }
 }
```

How would I implement this into my code? My double ShowArea is incorrect because radius is underlined. I think understanding this question would help with that issue. Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess ShowArea should be a method outside these classes that accepts a Shape then prints the area property, not a method on Circle. Arun's answer is a step in the right direction but I'd guess it should be saving the computed area to area, which you don't need to override unless you're planning to store the radius and compute it dynamically on get (and then you'd need to implement set to to reverse the calculation and save the radius)

Comment: Incidentally the reason you're getting underlines for radius here is because you're initialising your field ShowArea at object creation time, when radius has not been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, ShowArea is a method and not a field. Which means your Circle class should be something like:

```
public class Circle : Shape
{
    double _radius;

    // Constructor for the Circle that has radius as a parameter
    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        _radius = radius;
    } 

    // Method that returns the area of the circle using radius value from constructor
    public double ShowArea() 
    {
        return Math.Pi * Math.Pow(_radius, 2.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: An argument is just what the user enters and it is put in the parenthesis after the method?

Comment: That's right! In this case, because you're already providing the radius in the constructor, we can just use that value for the method ShowArea. But otherwise, you'd have to provide an argument for a method like I did originally.

Answer (score 0):

Your class design must be reviewed.

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        Radius = radius;
    }

    private double Radius { get; set; }


    public override double Area => 3.14 * Math.Pow(Radius, 2);
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public Square(double edge)
    {
        Edge = edge;
    }

    private double Edge { get; set; }


    public override double Area => Math.Pow(Edge, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of the method `ShowArea` is not correct. You are declaring a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) instead. 
You should read up more on [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods). You were also tasked to declare a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) with a parameter to set the `radius`, which I don't find it in your code.